# jquery function inside a function

Tags: javascript, function

Is it possible to have a function within another function like so?

```
function foo() {

    // do something

    function bar() {

        // do something

    }

    bar();

}

foo();
```

Comment: @ gion_13: strictly speaking having a function within a function is not a "closure". The aspect that the function will preserve any variables in its scope even if they are not part of the function body itself (i.e. non-local variables) makes it a "closure".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes you can have it like that. `bar` won't be visible to anyone outside `foo`.

And you can call `bar` inside `foo` as:

```
function foo() {

    // do something

    function bar() {

        // do something

    }
    bar();

}
```

Comment: I updated the code a little, is that still possible? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: :). Just added that to my answer. Yes you can.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can.
Or you can do this,

```
function foo(){

    (function(){

        //do something here

    })()

}
```

Or this,

```
function foo(){

    var bar=function(){

        //do something here

    }

}
```

Or you want the function "bar" to be universal,

```
function foo(){

    window.bar=function(){

        //something here

    }

}
```

Hop this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

That's called a nested function in Javascript.  The inner function is private to the outer function, and also forms a closure.  More details are available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures).

Be particularly careful of variable name collisions, however.  A variable in the outer function is visible to the inner function, but not vice versa.

Comment: Where exactly do I 'mean scope'?

Comment: "A variable in the outer function is visible to the inner function, but not vice versa." @Brennon

Comment: I see what you mean, but there's a reason I stated it that way.  Because of the mechanics of the closure, I wanted to spell it out a bit more.